# SQL: Using alias of a column in a function in the same select statement

Tags: sql

I am just trying to simplify a Select statement:

```
Select (a+b+c)/3 AS V, MIN((a+b+c)/3) as Min, MAX((a+b+c)/3) as Max from ....
```

Is there a clean way to avoid repeating that formula (a+b+c)/3 in the aggregate functions?

Comment: Keep in mind that the first select expression will be random (assuming mysql and no group by)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  Result/3 AS V, 
  MIN(Result/3) as Min, 
  MAX(Result/3) as Max
FROM
(
  SELECT (a+b+c) AS Result from Table
) AS outerTable
```

OR even

```
SELECT 
  Result AS V, 
  MIN(Result) as Min, 
  MAX(Result) as Max
FROM
(
  SELECT (a+b+c)/3 AS Result from Table
) AS outerTable
```

Comment: +1 but you could perhaps simplify it even further by doing the division in the inner select.

Comment: I'm wondering future SQL standard can support **use alias in same select list to avoid sub query**

Answer (score 1):

If you need the value `(a+b+c)/3` in more than just one query and your SQL dialect supports views, you might want to consider using a View.

The following code can be used in `MySQL` to create a View that contains all columns of the table  `MY_TABLE_NAME` + an additional column that contains the value `(a+b+c)/3`.

```
CREATE ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED
SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW  `MY_TABLE_NAME_FULL_VIEW` AS
SELECT MY_TABLE_NAME.*, (a+b+c)/3 AS Average
   FROM  `MY_TABLE_NAME`;
```

The following code can be used in `MySQL` to create a View that contains only the columns a, b and c + an additional column that contains the value `(a+b+c)/3`.

```
CREATE ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED
SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW  `MY_TABLE_NAME_LIMITED_VIEW` AS
SELECT a, b, c, (a+b+c)/3 AS Average
   FROM  `MY_TABLE_NAME`;
```

The following code can be used in `MySQL` to create a View in MySQL that contains only the value `(a+b+c)/3`.

```
CREATE ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED
SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW  `MY_TABLE_NAME_AVERAGE_VIEW` AS
SELECT (a+b+c)/3 AS Average
   FROM  `MY_TABLE_NAME`;
```

After you created your view, use the view instead of the table in your select queries.

---

Assuming you created view `MY_TABLE_NAME_AVERAGE_VIEW`, you could replace your `SELECT` statement with this :

```
SELECT Average AS V, MIN(Average) AS Min, MAX(Average) AS Max
FROM MY_TABLE_NAME_AVERAGE_VIEW;
```

Assuming you created view `MY_TABLE_NAME_LIMITED_VIEW`, and you also need to include values a, b and C, you could replace your `SELECT` statement with this :

```
SELECT a, b, c, Average AS V, MIN(Average) AS Min, MAX(Average) AS Max
FROM MY_TABLE_NAME_LIMITED_VIEW;
```